# What are the Race and Profession combinations?

Tags: guild-wars-2

While I am not a fan of the original guild wars I am believing in the hype that this one is different and I may enjoy it. But after poking around on the official website I am at a loss as for what race/profession combinations are possible. It seems like this information is purposefully misleading. So I come here!

Which races can be which profession? If I wanted to play a thief, for example, am I limited in my selections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All races can be all professions. There are no limitations.

Comment: Oh, well that clears that up.. I wish they had been a bit more straight forward, their 'playing as a ...' section was a bit misleading to make me think there was only 3-4 play styles per race available. Thanks!

Comment: On an added note, you might want to poke around with each class in general.  Guild Wars 2 definitely breaks a lot of RPG "traditions" from race choices (halflings/shortest race must be thieves!  Not in gw2....) to profession (thieves can't heal!  But they can in gw2....).

It's refreshing and sometimes intimidating.  With no clear obvious choice, you want to make sure you don't "break" your character with early decisions that won't translate later.  Again, not really an issue in Guild Wars 2.